# C# :OnvifClientPTZ

Tags: c#, camera, zooming, pan, onvif

I am trying to develop a control IP camera with ONVIF.But I have a little problem of connect PTZ server of ONVIF.
Here is my code:

```
 private void PTZTest(DeviceClient client, double deviceTimeOffset, string ip, int port)
   {
        // Create Media object
        string xaddr = string.Format("http://{0}/onvif/device_service", txtIP.Text); 
        MediaClient mediaService = OnvifServices.GetOnvifMediaClient(xaddr, deviceTimeOffset, txtUser.Text, txtPassword.Text);

        // Create PTZ object
        string xaddr2 = string.Format("http://{0}/onvif/ptz_service",txtIP.Text);
        PTZClient ptzService = OnvifServices.GetOnvifPTZClient(xaddr2, deviceTimeOffset, txtUser.Text, txtPassword.Text);
// Get target profile
        Profile[] mediaProfiles = mediaService.GetProfiles();
        Profile mediaProfile = mediaService.GetProfile(mediaProfiles[0].token);
        PTZConfigurationOptions ptzConfigurationOptions = ptzService.GetConfigurationOptions(mediaProfile.PTZConfiguration.token);

        PTZ.PTZSpeed velocity = new PTZ.PTZSpeed();

        velocity.Zoom = new PTZ.Vector1D() { x = speed * ptzConfigurationOptions.Spaces.ContinuousZoomVelocitySpace[0].XRange.Max };
```

When I set a breakpoint at the line
 `PTZConfigurationOptions ptzConfigurationOptions = ptzService.GetConfigurationOptions(mediaProfile.PTZConfiguration.token);`  I got this error message:

> There was no listening endpoint on
>   http://192.168.123.2/onvif/ptz_service that could accept the message.
>   This is often due to an incorrect SOAP address or action. If present,
>   see the InnerException element for more information.

But I dont understand why I can have the list of the PTZ services and all the informations about the mediaService, but I couldn't get the ptzconfiguration option.

Does anyone know what's the problem exactly ? And how can I resolve it, please!

Comment: I need to see the status code from the response.  Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and capture request and response.  If you have a working application to then compare the 1st working request with non working request.  Then make the c# non working request look like working request.  Normal failure status codes are either 400s or 500s errors.

Answer (score 0):

Not every onvif device will host its PTZ service on the same endpoint. Generally the approach to use is to query the GetServices/GetCapabilities calls from the DeviceService. This is the only service that usually always has the same URL - "http://ip/onvif/device_service"

Approach to use is therefore(in pseudocode)

```
var devService =  OnvifServices.GetOnvifDeviceService("http://ip/onvif/device_service)
var services = devService.GetServices() or devService.GetCapabilities()
var ptzServiceInfo = services.Where(x => x.Name.Contains("Ptz));

var ptzServiceInfo = OnvifServices.GetPtzService(ptzServiceInfo.Url);
```

you do not use the device_server to do any ptz_service calls, you simply use it to do a lookup for the correct URL of the device service If you do the GetService call the response will include something like

```
<tds:Service> <tds:Namespace>onvif.org/ver20/ptz/wsdl</tds:Namespace> <tds:XAddr>ip/onvif/ptz</tds:XAddr> </tds:Service>
```

See [onvif.org/specs/core/ONVIF-Core-Specification-v250.pdf](https://www.onvif.org/specs/core/ONVIF-Core-Specification-v250.pdf) for more details

Comment: Thanks for the informations. But if i use the <device_service> to try to get the ptzConfigurationOptions, i got the (400) bad request. That's means the correctry IP of ptzService is < http://192.168.123.2/onvif/ptz_service>, no ? Please give more explications , thanks a lot